# Sort matrix from Boolean

Tags: python, pandas, boolean

I want to sort my data into two categories (True/False). I have a matrix "arr" = (2500,128,3) and an boolean Array "bool"=(2500,1), the problem is that i cant sort it with:

```
true = arr[bool]
false = arr[~bool]
```

due to the missing dimension in my Array.

If there are 10 events which are true, the shape of the Variables should look like this:

```
true = (10,128,3) 
false = (2490,128,3)
```

Comment: what's your question again?

Comment: I want to transform the matrix arr into two categories True and False. However the dimensions are not the same. I have 2500 Boolean values and a matrix of (2500,128,3).

Answer (score 1):

```
ary = np.random.rand(2500,128,3)
print(ary.shape)
>>> (2500L, 128L, 3L)

ary_bool = np.random.randint(0,2,size=(2500,1))
print(ary_bool.shape)
>>> (2500L, 1L)

true_mat = ary[ary_bool.squeeze() == 1]
false_mat = ary[ary_bool.squeeze() == 0]

print(true_mat.shape)
print(false_mat.shape)
>>> (1277L, 128L, 3L)
>>> (1223L, 128L, 3L)
```

Comment: Also, refer to [numpy.squeeze()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html#numpy-squeeze) doc : Remove single-dimensional entries from the shape of an array.